# Is it permitted that male person to have feminine job? And otherwise?

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy, gender-identity

Is it forbidden for a male person to have feminine job? If so, how is a feminine job defined according to halacha?

Likewise, is it forbidden for a female person to have a masculine job?

Comment: What is your criteria to define a "male" job. Majority? Historically?

Comment: Majority and historically.

Comment: Do you have sources to illustrate that indeed the jobs you cite as examples are both historically and by majority male jobs?

Comment: male nurse would be the obvious one for me, chefs have historically included males as well as females, possibly more so.

Comment: I think this question would probably work better if you remove the examples, which can be distracting, and simply ask whether there is a concept in Jewish law of jobs that are prohibited to one gender because they're usually done by the other.

Comment: I have edited your question. If you feel that the edit does not accurately reflect the question that you want to ask, please feel free to revert the edit.

Comment: "How is a feminine job defined according to halacha?" You're the one defining it in your comment; if you believe something to be a feminine job, I think you have to use your own criteria here, and probably ask about a specific job.

Comment: Ha! Oh, I see @IsaacMoses and I disagree. Maybe. I think it should focus on one job and ask if that's ok. My guess is that one job in particular sparked the question, so just ask about that.

Comment: @SethJ I'm with Isaac on this one. We have to know whether there is a halachic concept of a "feminine job" before we can go and start asking about specific jobs.

Comment: @SethJ, I agree that asking about *one* particular job would be a valid question and would be the right question to ask if that's what Win Aero really wants to know. If so, the post should contain information about why one might suspect that a prohibition applies to that job, the more convincing, the better.

Comment: I totally agree with you, @IsaacMoses. I don't disagree with Daniel, either, that the fundamental principal underlying the question about one job (or many) could stand to be defined, but I think it needs something concrete to tie it to in order for the question to work. Or it needs a complete overhaul (which I'm not prepared to invest in).

Comment: @Daniel see my comment just above this one.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps we could look at the question from a different angle. If a male were to work in a field which is predominantly female, then presumanbly he would come in contact with a lot of woman.

Assuming that is the case, the Gemara in Kiddushin (82a) prohibits such occupations:

> לא ילמד אדם את בנו אומנות נשים
>
> "A person should not teach his son a trade that requires that he be
> among women."

If a man's profession requires that he be constantly with women (and often alone with these women), it can result in sin. The Talmud lists trades that require that a person often be alone with women:

> Our Rabbis taught: Whoever’s business is with women has bad character,
> for example: goldsmiths [who make jewelry for women], carders,
> handmill cleaners, door-to-door perfume salesmen, barbers [women bring
> their children to him for haircuts], launderers, bloodletters,
> bathhouse attendants, and tanners [who make clothing from skins for
> women]. These cannot be made appointed neither as kings nor as high
> priests. Why? Not because they are legally disqualified; but because
> their profession is undignified

(Babylonian Talmud, Kiddushin 82a).

The Talmud (Kiddushin 40a) relates the story of

> Rabbi Kahana who used to sell baskets to women. One day, a Roman
> matron tried to force him to have illicit relations with her. To
> escape, he went to the roof and flung himself from it. Elijah the
> prophet caught him and complained that he had to travel a distance of
> four hundred parsangs to save him. Rabbi Kahana explained that it was
> his great poverty that caused him to go into this line of work. Elijah
> gave him a vessel filled with golden dinarim.

(translation and explanation from [this site](http://www.jlaw.com/Articles/idealoccupa.html)).

Although there is no mention of women working in predominantly male occupations which would bring her into contact with them, nonetheless, IMO, the underlying essence and spirit of the Rabbis concern as quoted above, would apply equally to women just as much as men.

In summation, there seems to be no such thing as a male job, or a female job in halacha, but rather jobs that are conducive to spirituality as summarized by the site linked above:

> SUMMARY AND CONCLUSION
>
> The ideal occupation has the following characteristics:
>
> (1) It provides an individual with time to pursue spiritual pursuits.
>
> (2) It does not tempt one to become dishonest or sexually immoral.
>
> (3) It allows one to help people and society.
>
> (4) It is profitable and enables one to become wealthy.
>
> (5) It is clean, pleasant, and dignified work.
>
> (6) It is not overly strenuous.

Comment: The same prohibition as a man not wearing a dress (לא תלבד גבר etc.) also applies to looking at a mirror. Perhaps doing a "woman job" is like looking in a mirror.

Comment: I dont agree mirros and the like imo have nothing to do with this discussion, and hamotzi mechaveiro alav harayah.

Comment: `the Gemara in Kiddushin (82a) prohibits such occupations`...`A person should not teach his son` Recommendations and outright prohibitions are two different things. The quote thus does not support the claim.